# tar Cannot open: No such file or directory

Tags: centos, tar, gzip

Fresh install of CentOS 5.4

Downloaded the following:

```
http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin-1.510.tar.gz
```

MD5 sum is correct (`cdcc09d71d85d81914a90413eaf21d3f`). The file is located here:

```
/tmp/webmin-1.510.tar.gz
```

`tmp` and `webmin-1.510.tar.gz` both have `chmod 777`. I am logged in as root.

Command:

```
tar -zxfv webmin-1.510.tar
```

Result:

```
tar: v: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: webmin-1.510.tar: Not found in archive
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Never run across this before. It's like it thinks that `v` is a file I want to extract, but its one of the command arguments...

If I leave out the `v`...

```
tar -zxf webmin-1.510.tar.gz
```

The command stalls. It doesn't do anything.  Just goes to the next line and no prompt comes up. I have to CTRL-C to get back to the prompt and a `ls` verifies that it didn't extract anything...

My first reaction is that its not a valid tar/gz file or something. But the MD5 matches just fine. So I'm at a loss just a bit...

**UPDATE**

Wow. Never new that the order of the arguments mattered. Wonder why I've never noticed it after all these years.

However I just tried

```
tar -zxvf webmin-1.510.tar.gz
```

And the terminal is still stalled and I have to CTRL-C to get a prompt again. And to reiterate myself, if I `ls` there is NO `webmin-1.510` directory after this procedure. Nothing is extracted.

**UPDATE 2**

I also just gunzipp'ed the file, so now I have a `webmin-1.510.tar`. I just tried the following:

```
tar -xvf webmin-1.510.tar
```

And again, same result. The command stalls the terminal and I have to CTRL-C to get a prompt. Nothing extracted.

Comment: Responding to Update 2:  Do you have `strace` on your system?  Running the same command under `strace` (`strace tar -xvf webmin-1.510.tar`) may provide clues.

Comment: Your tar could be perverse and interpret the `-` as "read archive from stdin". Some really old versions of tar didn't grok the `-` as an option signifier and weren't too picky about argument order. I'm guessing Ctrl-D (EOF) will stop your "stalled" tar. Modern GNU-tar accepts `tar xvf foo.tar` in homage to the old ways.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The 'f' option needs to come at the end.  It tells tar that what follows is the tarball name.  Your command should be:

```
tar -zxvf webmin-1.510.tar.gz
```

The 'v' option is for verbose output.  I bet if you did an 'ls' in the current directory, there's going to be a webmin-1.510 or such directory.

Comment: No, `-f` doesn't need to come at the end. But it needs to be directly followed by the argument it expects: the tar file name. Then, other options can follow behind: `tar -f webmin-1.510.tar.gz -zxv` would be OK. (But it seems there was also some other problem which led to the original question)
`

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
Go to root if necessary:
# sudo su
# cd ~
# wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin-1.510.tar.gz
# tar -xvvzf webmin-1.510.tar.gz
```

It should now be extracted. It's possible system can't untar from and to your /tmp dir.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, but it turned out that I wasn't logged in as the user that owned the file. Once I logged it the file unzipped fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).