# Extracting tar file: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, debian, tar

I have a remote Debian 5 machine on which I'm trying to extract a tar-file (Django 1.2.1, but that's unimportant). The first 1300 or so files extracts just fine (of about 2800 in total), after which errors like

```
tar: Django-1.2.1/tests/urls.py: Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

shows up for the rest of the files, finally ending up with a

```
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

I use the command

```
tar xzvf Django-1.2.1.tar.gz
```

I've also tried with sudo (but I'm extracting in my home directory, which I should obviusly have permissions to use without). I've tried gunzipping first (runs flawlessly) and then running tar xvf, but to no avail. I've fetched the file using wget:

```
wget http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.2.1/tarball/
```

I've tried redownloading it several times.

A test as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/150777/tar-cannot-open-no-such-file-or-directory/150796#150796) simply lists all files in the archive (notably with "james" as owner, which is not my username - but I suppose it's the username of the guy who created the archive - not sure if that is significant).

Finally, I should note that both extration methods works fine on my local Ubuntu installating and that there is plenty of free disk space on the remote box.

So, now I have sort of run out of good ideas :-) Suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you checked that you have enough space on the remote machine, maybe your disk is accidentally filling up

Comment: Yep. There are several gigabytes free.

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong, apparently. Even though the df command claims there is gigabytes of free space on the /home partition, I can't even create a new folder because of lack of disk space. After moving the tarball elsewhere, I can extract it. Thanks for making me check more thoroughly :-)

Comment: yea, you could have been hitting a user quota limit, or been on another partition and not realized it

Comment: Perhaps you hit the inode limit on that partition. See what df -i tells you.